# What book has prices for alternative muses?

Tags: eclipse-phase, books

In the *Eclipse Phase* core rule book, 
there are rules for buying a muse.
It is listed with stats and a price in the section with other AIs like Vecheil AIs and Hacking (Kaos) AIs.
It notes that all PCs start with a muse.

Because it is statted and has a price,
presumably by paying more you can get a better one.
Do any books provide muse improvements/upgrades?

I had a look in *Transhuman*, which gives some suggestions on interacting with muses, but not much beyond fluff.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good discussion of how to break out the costs of muse improvement over at the official Eclipse Phase forum: http://www.eclipsephase.com/nonstandard-muses . Note the people who inhabit the forums are pretty hard core into *EP*, so if they're coming up with their own rules for this in the forum, it's because it's not covered in the books.

Answer (score 1):

There is a muse upgrade available in Rimward (page 199) for "Titanian Muses":

> Titanian muses commonly have the following skills: Academics: History 60, Academics: Political Science 60, Interest: Parliamentary Procedure 60, and Profession: Law 60. A common muse upgrade, the Plurality package, contains all of these skills and may be acquired from several Titanian microcorps at a cost of [Moderate].

Interestingly, that source book also describes a custom Jovian muse called a "minder", but there are no stats, so perhaps that is just a standard morph and the extra functionality is roleplayed if necessary.

Transhuman (page 168) indirectly warns against improving the skills and aptitudes of a muse:

> Obviously the muse should not be a crutch that always has perfect advice. They have significant limitations, namely their low aptitudes and small selection of skills. Gamemasters should only use muses as a way to advise players when they are not taking certain options or clues that they should know into account.

In roleplaying terms, you could say muses have a specific hardware specification and therefore cannot physically raise their skills or aptitudes above this level. Muses are also designed to perform a specific function, effectively act as a Siri and companionship, so their base set of skills *makes sense*. I seriously question why a player would want to make a custom muse, other than to try and game the system.

It will also get to an "uncanny valley" level if you do so - with sufficiently high aptitudes, is the muse sentient?

That's not to stop you creating a souped-up muse for an NPC enemy, for an adventure exploring the limits of muse technology. My advice would be to not afford that ability to the players.

Comment: He wanted to spend more money on his muse, solely for the prestige. He was a hypercorp elite. So the idea of using a simple consumer grade muse? 
He has never, and probably will never roll a test with his muse -- he took the muse skill set himself.